# Different layout based on post amount?

Tags: query-posts, query, screen-layout

Is it possible to change the layout of the query posts depending on how many there are?

So simple query page listing posts...

Up to 4 posts show them in a list.

If there are 4 posts and over show them as float blocks for example.

Answer (score 1):

for a standard query, you can check the amount of posts with:

all posts for the query:
`$wp_query->found_posts`

and the posts on the page:
`$wp_query->post_count`

use that with a conditional statement to switch to the different layouts.

example:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : //start of the loop//
  if ( $wp_query->found_posts <= 4 ) { ?>
     list output of posts 
      //this will need to include the 'while(have_posts())' including the 'endwhile' of the loop
  <?php } else { ?>
     float block output
     //this will need to include the 'while(have_posts())' including the 'endwhile' of the loop
     <?php } 
endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Michael, i'm unsure how to attach them to a normal query and subsequent conditional statement though..

Comment: Show us your query

Comment: I have added an example structure

Comment: Thank you Michael, i've tried your code here.. http://pastie.org/7629448 and it doesn't work it just shows the second half whether its 2 posts or 10...

Comment: what theme are you using? what it the output if you add `echo $wp_query->found_posts;` before the code

Comment: An empty theme Starkers its called, when i put that in it just prints 50 which is the amount of published posts i have

Comment: that is right; if you are referring to the number of posts on the 'paged' page, then use `$wp_query->post_count`